# Why won't this PHP iteration work?

Tags: php, iteration, concatenation

I want to make the results of a foreach loop into a string variable I can use later all over (so I don't need to paste the foreach loop everywhere). I have this:

```
foreach($pairs as $d=>$m) {
$orderedpairs .= "[".$d."],[".$m."]"+"<br />";
}
echo $orderedpairs;
```

If I substitute the assignment operator with "echo", it works fine, so the loop is ok, I think it's just the variable assignment that's at issue. Thanks!

Comment: Side note: consider using printf or string interpolation to make it more readable. (1) $orderedpairs .= "[$d],[$m]<br />"; (2) $orderedpairs .= printf('[%s],[%s]<br />', $d, $m);

Comment: and don't forget to initialize $orderedpairs before the loop starts. omitting this is not a problem per se, but it should be done - otherwise notices may be thrown (and strange bugs or security holes may occur, remember register_global).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The plus sign is causing your concatenation to fail - change it to a `.`

*Contrary to what others are saying*, the scope of your variable is not the problem. You **CAN declare them inside a loop and access them after it**. PHP variables are not scoped like Java, C#, and other languages.

Comment: was just writing the same thing!

Comment: It works now with just zapping the "+". Can you explain a bit further why I need to define $orderedpairs outside the loop? It seems like the scope isn't an issue. Is it just a style thing?

Comment: PHP scoping is simpler than some other languages. Variables really only have a "global" or a "function" scope - if a variable is declared inside of a function it is accessible anytime after declaration within that function. It doesn't matter if it's inside an if statement, while loop, or any other block that would be considered a more narrow scope in a language like Java.

Comment: I wouldn't even say a style thing for $orderedpairs - I'd set it just before the start of the loop so I knew it was empty. Also, an undeclared variable would throw a warning.

Answer (score 12):

You have a + in there for concatenation.  You need .

Also, you should define $orderedpairs as an empty string before the loop.

Comment: It works when I zap that last "+". I haven't defined $orderedpairs, however. Can you expand on why I need to do that?

Answer (score 4):

There's actually no need to concatenate with the operator in your case, you can just do:

```
$orderedpairs .= "[$d],[$m]<br />";
```

and PHP will replace the variables with their values.

Answer (score 0):

Has $orderedpairs been declared as an empty string before the loop to instantiate and bring it into scope?  Also should the final + actually be a . ?